# PJAX Multiple Containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

How can I create a Pjax that can have multiple containers? I tried this Pjax on this link:

https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/README.md

and this is my code:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container, #pjax-navbar');
```

but it doesn't work.

then I tried this code:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-navbar');
```

and it doesn't work either. It just loads the last one.

How do I make it work?

this is my HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar" role="navigation" id="pjax-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="/josh/cms_template/backend/web/">My Company</a></div>
            <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/josh/cms_template/backend/web/site/index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/josh/cms_template/backend/web/site/logout" data-method="post">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
        <div class="site-index">
            this is my content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

all i want is when i go to another page, only pjax-container will changing.

i already make it. but the navigation bar is not changing.

Comment: Please add html layout;

Comment: Please add html layout. When that code executed ? Maybe pjax handler doesn't attached correctly to page.

Answer (score 1):

Pjax doesn't have multiple containers.

To copy the same response to other pjax container, you can use pjax complete event handler like this.

Remove/disable existing pjax code from your page:

```
//Remove Code

//$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
//$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-navbar')
//$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container, #pjax-navbar');


// Add this Code

$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(event) {
   //This code will copy #pjax-container container's response 
   // to #pjax-navbar when event is completed.

   $('#pjax-navbar').html(  $('#pjax-container').html() );

});
```

Comment: i just want is to change the container when i go to other page.

i already make it. but the navigation bar is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two links with same href but different id.
And attach pjax to each of them:

```
$(document).pjax('a#pjax-link-container', '#pjax-container');
$(document).pjax('a#pjax-link-navbar', '#pjax-navbar');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
$(document).on('pjax:clicked', function(options) { 
                $.pjax.reload('#pjax-container', {               
                 fragment: '#pjax-container',
                 timeout: 5000,
                 scrollTo: false
              })
            });
```